# constructing dynamic In Statements with sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Suppose we need to check three boolean conditions to perform a select query. Let the three flags be 'A', 'B' and 'C'.

If all of the three flags are set to '1' then the query to be generated is 
SELECT * FROM Food WHERE Name In ('Apple, 'Biscuit', 'Chocolate');
If only the flags 'A' and 'B' are set to '1' with C set to '0'. Then the following query is generated.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Food 
 WHERE Name In ('Apple, 'Biscuit');
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Were you thinking of constructing this dynamic SQL in a computer programming language?  Any particular one?

Comment: The SQL dialect to be used is T-SQL.

Comment: T-SQL means Sybase and/or SQL Server

Comment: Can you clue us in on the data types of your flags?  Do you intend on sending 3 booleans?  ... keys?  ... bitwise flags (00, 01, 10, 11)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Food
 WHERE (Name = 'Apple' AND <condition A>)
    OR (Name = 'Biscuit' AND <condition B>)
    OR (Name = 'Chocolate' AND <condition C>)
```

Now, while being correct this is not desirable from performance point of view since conditions A, B, and C are not data driven (they don not change from row to row). So you can use permutations of all possible conditions by constructing SQL dynamically - use IN clause and construct its string dynamically.

Yet another solution is assembling final result in the client by running each SELECT separately (pseudo-code):

```
if A then {
   result1 = execute("SELECT * FROM Food WHERE Name = 'Apple')
}
if B then {
   result2 = execute("SELECT * FROM Food WHERE Name = 'Biscuit')
}
if C then {
   result2 = execute("SELECT * FROM Food WHERE Name = 'Chocolate')
}

result = join(result1, result2, result3)
```

This solution may work when you have high percentage of cases with just one or two true conditions.

Comment: I like the first solution, the second one incurs more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

First may be you need to check if all are false and show error. Or may be not if it is acceptable in your case.

Then if these flags are mere bool variables do (pseudocode)

```
sql = "SELECT * 
  FROM Food 
 WHERE Name In (";
if (A) sql += "'Apple', "
if (B) sql += "'Biscuit', "
if (C) sql += "'Chocolate', "
sql = sql.deleteLastCharacter() + ");";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you include A/B/C in the query?
select * from food where (name = 'Apple' or NOT A) and (name = 'Biscuit' OR NOT B)...

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be read: [Dynamic SQL](http://www.benkotips.com/Default.aspx?tabid=631).

The [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) system stored procedure reveals to be pretty useful also.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really complex topic that has many subtle performance implications. You really need to read these excellent articles by Erland Sommarskog:

[Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)